# Saving output of mplayer

Tags: mplayer

How can I save the output of mplayer?

For example, if to play slowly an mp3 file, I use `mplayer -speed 0.6 file.mp3`. However, `mplayer -speed 0.6 file.mp3 > file2.mp3` won't save the output to a file (which should be just the same, but slower).

Any alternative command-line solution is welcome too, I am not tied to mplayer.

Answer (score 5):

Try mencoder instead:

```
mencoder -speed 0.6 -o output_file file.mp3
```

Comment: @nwildner It sure seems to. `mplayer` and `mencoder` are part of the same toolkit, and the question even says "Any alternative command-line solution is welcome too, I am not tied to mplayer."

Comment: I agree, it seems a _very_ appropriate answer, though I could have expanded on the audio-specific options of mencoder.   I'm not too invested in the competition, just trying to help.